# Squeryl select top

Tags: select, squeryl

I would like to do something like the following but using Squeryl:

select top 10 * 
from table
where conditionA = a

so far I can only get to:
table.where(x => x.conditionA = a).head

The problem with this is the db call gets all the records that meets the condition from the db, while I only need the top one.

I cannot find another way to do the select top in Squeryl which only brings the necessary amount of records back from db.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squeryl has a method called [`page`](http://squeryl.org/pagination.html) which you can use to specify a LIMIT and OFFSET for the query.

In your example; `table.where(x => x.conditionA === a).page(0, 10).toList` should achieve what you are looking to do.